# Grouping a list in python specifically

Tags: python, sorting

Hi is there anyway to group this list such that it would return a string(first element) and a list within a `tuple` for each equivalent first element?

ie.,

> [('106', '1', '1', '43009'), ('106', '1', '2', '43179'), ('106', '1', '4', '43619'), ('171', '1', '3', '59111'), ('171', '1', '4', '57089'), ('171', '1', '5', '57079'), ('184', '1', '18', '42149'), ('184', '1', '19', '12109'), ('184', '1', '20', '12099')]

becomes :

> [('106',[('106', '1', '1', '43009'), ('106', '1', '2', '43179'), ('106', '1', '4', '43619')]),
>   ('171',[('171', '1', '3', '59111'), ('171', '1', '4', '57089'), ('171', '1', '5', '57079')]),
>   ('184'[(('184', '1', '18', '42149'), ('184', '1', '19', '12109'), ('184', '1', '20', '12099')])]

Comment: Is your input list _already sorted_ by the first element in each tuple?

Comment: it seems to me the order hasn't changed. why do you call it *sort*?

Comment: Good point @KarolyHorvath, edited.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: you shouldn't just rephrase the question. wait for approval first.

Comment: Sorry, still new to python, not really sure on the terms! Is there a way to do this without imports?

Comment: Yes, but why? You can adjust my answer to use `setdefault`, which requires no imports - but don't give yourself such arbitrary restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is going to be already sorted, then you can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), like this

```
from itertools import groupby
print [(i,) + (list(g),) for i, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

**Output**

```
[('106',
  [('106', '1', '1', '43009'),
   ('106', '1', '2', '43179'),
   ('106', '1', '4', '43619')]),
 ('171',
  [('171', '1', '3', '59111'),
   ('171', '1', '4', '57089'),
   ('171', '1', '5', '57079')]),
 ('184',
  [('184', '1', '18', '42149'),
   ('184', '1', '19', '12109'),
   ('184', '1', '20', '12099')])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in big_list:
   d[i[0]].append(i)
```

Now that you have the items accessible by your key, which is the first item, you can sort the keys and access the dictionary in your order:

```
sorted_keys = sorted(d.keys(), key=int)

for key in sorted_keys:
    print(d[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary with the first element as key. 
Also look into ordered dictionaries.